# Checking condition in future rows in pandas with group by

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Following is what my dataframe looks like and `Expected_Output` is my desired column.

```
  Group  Signal  Value1  Value2  Expected_Output
0      1       0       3       1              NaN
1      1       1       4       2              NaN
2      1       0       7       4              NaN
3      1       0       8       9              1.0
4      1       0       5       3              NaN
5      2       1       3       6              NaN
6      2       1       1       2              1.0
7      2       0       3       4              1.0
```

For a given `Group`, if `Signal == 1`, then I am attempting to look at the next three rows(and not the current row) and check if `Value1 < Value2`. If that condition is true, then I return a 1 in the `Expected_Output` column. If for example, `Value < Value2` condition is satisfied for multiple reasons as it comes within 3 next rows from `Signal == 1` in both row 5 & 6(`Group 2`), then I am also returning a 1 in `Expected_Output`.

I am assuming the right combination of `group by object`,`np.where`, `any`, `shift` could be the solution but cant quite get there.

N.B:- Alexander pointed out a conflict in the comments. Ideally, a value being set due to a signal in a prior row will supersede the current row rule conflict in a given row.

Comment: @Alexander They are treated separately. The confusing part for me was how to converge multiple `Expected_Output = 1` outputs on the same row when they are being satisfied by multiple signals within  the group.

Comment: For the expected output on row 6, shouldn't that be `NaN`? The reason being is that row six has a signal value of one, thus creating a new group where the current row is ignored.  I realize that the value was set due to the signal on row 5, but my question is really how you intend to handle conflicts such as this.

Comment: @Alexander Ideally, a value being set due to a signal in a prior row will supersede the current row rule conflict in a given row. Thank you for pointing out the conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to be checking lots of previous rows, multiple shifts can quickly get messy, but here it's not too bad:

```
s = df.groupby('Group').Signal

condition = ((s.shift(1).eq(1) | s.shift(2).eq(1) | s.shift(3).eq(1)) 
                & df.Value1.lt(df.Value2))

df.assign(out=np.where(condition, 1, np.nan))
```

```
   Group  Signal  Value1  Value2  out
0      1       0       3       1  NaN
1      1       1       4       2  NaN
2      1       0       7       4  NaN
3      1       0       8       9  1.0
4      1       0       5       3  NaN
5      2       1       3       6  NaN
6      2       1       1       2  1.0
7      2       0       3       4  1.0
```

If you're concerned about the performance of using so many shifts, I wouldn't worry too much, here's a sample on 1 million rows:

```
In [401]: len(df)
Out[401]: 960000

In [402]: %%timeit
     ...: s = df.groupby('Group').Signal
     ...:
     ...: condition = ((s.shift(1).eq(1) | s.shift(2).eq(1) | s.shift(3).eq(1))
     ...:                 & df.Value1.lt(df.Value2))
     ...:
     ...: np.where(condition, 1, np.nan)
     ...:
     ...:
94.5 ms ± 524 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

@Alexander identified a conflict in the rules, here is a version using a mask that fits that requirement:

```
s = (df.Signal.mask(df.Signal.eq(0)).groupby(df.Group)
        .ffill(limit=3).mask(df.Signal.eq(1)).fillna(0))
```

Now you can simply use this column along with your other condition:

```
np.where((s.eq(1) & df.Value1.lt(df.Value2)).astype(int), 1, np.nan)
```

```
array([nan, nan, nan,  1., nan, nan, nan,  1.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index that matches your criteria, and then use it to set the expected output to 1.

It is not clear how to treat the expected output when the rules conflict.  For example, on row 6, the expected output would be 1 because it satisfied the signal criteria from row five and fits 'the subsequent three rows where value 1 < value 2'.  However, it possibly conflicts with the rule that the first signal row is ignored.

```
idx = (df
       .assign(
           grp=df['Signal'].eq(1).cumsum(),
           cond=df.eval('Value1 < Value2'))
       .pipe(lambda df: df[df['grp'] > 0])  # Ignore data preceding first signal.
       .groupby(['Group', 'grp'], as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda df: df.iloc[1:4, :])  # Ignore current row, get rows 1-3. 
       .pipe(lambda df: df[df['cond']])  # Find rows where condition is met.
       .index.get_level_values(1)
)

df['Expected_Output'] = np.nan
df.loc[idx, 'Expected_Output'] = 1

>>> df
   Group  Signal  Value1  Value2  Expected_Output
0      1       0       3       1              NaN
1      1       1       4       2              NaN
2      1       0       7       4              NaN
3      1       0       8       9              1.0
4      1       0       5       3              NaN
5      2       1       3       6              NaN
6      2       1       1       2              NaN  # <<< Intended difference vs. "expected"
7      2       0       3       4              1.0
```

Comment: For the condition you are matching, I think it would be much simpler and perform to mask `Signal` where it equals `0`, ffill 3 forward per group, then replace the initial `1s` with zeros.  It removes the need for any sort of `apply`